# Gorilla session package confusion

Tags: session, go, gorilla

Coming from a PHP background I'm a little confuse about Gorilla sessions package.

Does Gorilla act similar to `$_SESSION['name']` or does it act similar to `$_COOKIE['name']` from PHP?

I'm trying to use both ways to create a user session for my Go web application, but I'm not sure if Gorilla sessions will be a good package to use. I want the users who didn't click on the "remember me" button on the login form to have their session erased after closing their browser, whereas everyone else will have a cookie associated with them. So would Gorilla sessions be able to handle both scenarios or should I use something else in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It entirely depends on which storage back-end you use.

The [gorilla/sessions](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/sessions) package has built-in cookie & filesystem based stores. There is no memory-based store, which is roughly what PHP's `$_SESSION` is.

My recommendation:

- Use the built-in cookie store, which uses signed cookies. It is well suited for most purposes and is the easiest to implement.
- If you have a need for server-side sessions (i.e. storing large values in the session), [pick from the available implementations](https://github.com/gorilla/sessions#store-implementations) - Redis, BoltDB, mySQL, Postgres, etc.

I have first-hand experience with the Redis backed store ([redistore](https://github.com/boj/redistore)), which has been great. The BoltDB (a file-based key store) and Postgres stores are also solid if you have a preference for those.

> I want the users who didn't click on the "remember me" button on the login form to have their session erased after closing their browser, whereas everyone else will have a cookie associated with them. So would Gorilla sessions be able to handle both scenarios or should I use something else in this case?

Note that all implementations require a "cookie" - it's just whether the cookie is the self-contained store, or whether it just holds an identifier referring to a row/value in the back-end store.

You can set "session cookies" (i.e. last only as long as the tab/browser session) by setting `session.Options.MaxAge = 0` as per [this part of the gorilla/sessions docs](https://github.com/gorilla/sessions/blob/master/sessions.go#L24-L32).

e.g.

```
func MyHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    session, err := store.Get(r, "session-name")
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), 500)
        return
    }

    // Add your logic to check the r.FormValue for your remember_me checkbox.

    // Temporary session
    session.Options.MaxAge = 0

    // Set some session values.
    session.Values["user"] = someUser
    // Save it before we write to the response/return from the handler.
    session.Save(r, w)
}
```

Hope that helps.